# more than two independent lines in any curved surface

Tags: geometry

It is intuitively correct that there are at most two linearly independent vectors in the usual $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

And non-Euclidean geometry suggests that parallel lines can intersect in a sphere.

Is there any surface with some special setting where more than two segments
are orthogonal to each other?

Just for curiosity I got while reading a linear algebra book.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal segments"? It is not possible to choose more than two "locally independent" vectors as long as we are talking about 2-manifolds because they are locally just $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: "more than two segments are orthogonal to each other", is possible only  in $\mathbb{R}^n, n>2$